# How does the onClick() function works in ReactJS What is happening in Container Component and Presentational Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

"The Main class is the container component from where I am importing the Presentational component Menu"

"Regarding dishes.js, DishdetailComponent.js in Main class(where I am importing) these are just used for rendering purpose"

"I just want to know how the onClick() function is communicating with Menu class since there is an onClick()"

"What happens is that there is a list of items displayed on the screen where if an item is clicked the details of it is shown which is handled by another component.. I just want to know what is happening with the onClick() in Menu and the onClick() in Main are they working parallely ? "

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
    import { Navbar,NavbarBrand } from 'reactstrap'; 
    import Menu from './MenuComponent';
    import DishDetail from './DishdetailComponent';
    import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes';

    class Main extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          dishes:DISHES,
          selectedDish:null 
        };
      }

      onDishSelect(dishId){
        this.setState({selectedDish:dishId});
    }

      render(){ 
        return (
          <div> {/* class name app has been removed */}
            <Navbar dark color="primary">
              <div className="container">
                <NavbarBrand href="/">Ristorante Con Fusion</NavbarBrand>
              </div>
            </Navbar> 
            <Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} onClick={(dishId)=> this.onDishSelect(dishId)}/>


            <DishDetail 
            dish={this.state.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.id === this.state.selectedDish )[0]} />   
          </div>
        );
      } 

    }

    </script>
```

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';

class Menu extends Component { 

constructor(props){
        super(props); 
     }
render(){

    const menu=this.props.dishes.map( (dish) => {   
        return(
            <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">             
              <Card onClick={() => this.props.onClick(dish.id)}>  
                    <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name}  />
                    <CardImgOverlay body className="ml-4"> 
                            <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                    </CardImgOverlay>
              </Card>
            </div>
              );
    }) ; 

        return( 
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row"> 


                </div>

            </div>
            ); 
        }
        }
export default Menu;
```

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` on Menu component rendered in Main component is not an even handler but a prop passed on to the Menu component. For the sake of understand you can think of it like `handleClick`

The `onClick` on Card inside Menu is again a prop passed on to the Card component. Since card ccomponent is used from reactstrap, it internally would be rendering a div wherein it would attach an actual `onClick` handler

Now when the Card is clicked, the handler inside Card is trigger which then calls the onClick passed on as props to it and it further calls `this.props.onClick(dish.id)` which is the function passed on from `Menu` component.

The onClicks functions are not executed parallelly but sequentially communication information from child to the parent and further to the grandparent.

Comment: Thank you for the review I understood it but can you help me out in something I am confused...when the portion being clicked(it is a part of an array that i displayed on my page..where per index containing dish.id,dish.name,dish.img etc) so does the onClick work in this way that when clicked it will pass only dish.id as i have written in my code or the subarray that is chosen by the onClick

Comment: the onclick is only passed dish.id which you passed to onClick

Comment: thanks a bunch @Shubham it was really unclear at first and now I finally got it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your naming... It confuses you. The onClick attribute on your Menu is a property passed to your react Menu component. The this.props.onClick receives the function defined in the onClick attribute.

In your menu, the onClick attribute is set on a HTML element so that defines a click handler. It happens that your click handler executes the function in this.props.onClick which has been passed from the parent.

I suggest to change the property name to something more explicit, something like onDishSelection maybe?

Comment: Thank you for the review I understood it but can you help me out in something I am confused...when the portion being clicked(it is a part of an array that i displayed on my page..where per index containing dish.id,dish.name,dish.img etc)since i am displaying lists of food items in my array so does the onClick work in this way that when clicked,it will pass only dish.id as i have written in my code or the subarray that is chosen by the onClick